# Knightlabs Storymap plugin breaking CPT archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

The plugin [Storymaps](https://wordpress.org/plugins/storymaps/) by Knightlabs seems to be causing some kind of conflict with the archive page for one of my CPT.

I have a CPT called 'journal', for which I have setup an archive template called `archive-journal.php`, which up until installing this plugin worked perfectly. If I disable the plugin it functions correctly again. When the plugin is enabled the page ignores `archive.php` and reverts to `index.php`.

I have deregistered the script and stylesheet (see below) for the plugin (apart from on the page that uses it) but no luck.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

```
function kmp_deregister_plugins() {
    if ( !is_page('map') ) { // All pages except 'map'
        wp_deregister_script( 'storymap-javascript' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'storymap-stylesheet' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kmp_deregister_plugins', 100 );
```

The problem that I have is - No content is loaded whatsoever apart from the header, sidebar and footer. I have inserted some code to identify the template being used and it is defaulting to `index.php` for some reason?

When debug is set to true in wp-config, I see the following? I have no idea what this means?

> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use __construct() instead. in /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3619 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/functions.php:3619) in /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: What actual problem is it causing on your archive page?

Comment: Hi @JamesJones, no content is loaded whatsoever apart from the header, sidebar and footer. I have inserted some code to identify the template being used and it is defaulting to index.php for some reason?

Comment: When debug is set to true in wp-config, I see the following? I have no idea what this means?

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3619

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/functions.php:3619) in /homepages/26/d247113712/htdocs/kurdmem/staging/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: Added the problem statement that was given in comments and the debugger message into the question. Always add all relevant information into the question itself. Comments can go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your errors, it seems like `wp_redirect()` is being called. This is line 1228 in `/wp-includes/pluggable.php` This might explain why you're being taken to `index.php` rather than the archive you want.

Storymaps doesn't have any instance of `wp_redirect()`, but there is a plugin that Storymaps requires called 'Advanced Custom Fields' which does have an instance of `wp_redirect()` in the function `acf_form_head()` in `\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\core\api.php`. I presume you also have this plugin installed and active. You might want to check if that is being called. Maybe then you can work back from there.

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for the information. I know that if I deactivate the Storymaps and ACF plugins everything works fine, but I am stuck as to how to resolve this conflict. If you have any suggestions in addition to the above that would be great. I don't want to edit any core plugin files as I will end up not being able to update them in the future?

Comment: ACF has a github at https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf. You can clone their repo, make changes and then do a pull request. Or you can simply contact the plugin authors. Someone will need to do the diagnoses and changes, whether you or the author s.